# Android: ImageView load from URL

Tags: android, url, bitmap, bitmapimage

Tried many ways in the internet but my imageView still display blank of the image.
Wish to retrieve the image from url (download or refer it) but seems I missed out something.
I have activated the INTERNET permission in manifest.

```
 icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.portrait_user);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/t1.0-1/c0.0.50.50/p50x50/1499583_10202305028778787_1063740680_n.jpg");
            InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
            Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content);
            icon.setImageBitmap(d);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why you reinventing the wheel instead of using one of many existing, much better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Doing network I/O on the main application thread like this will crash your app on Android 4.0+.

Most likely, you will be better served using a third-party library that can download the image for you in the background and update the `ImageView` when it is ready. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) are two of the more popular libraries for this.

Comment: I'm only need to load one image, thought I could use the Android code.

Comment: @shoujo_sm: You are certainly welcome to set up your own `AsyncTask`, doing the download and `BitmapFactory` work in `doInBackground()`, and populating your `ImageView` in `onPostExecute()`. That too has issues, such as dealing with configuration changes. Beyond that, I would suggest using `Log.e()` rather than `printStackTrace()` to ensure that your logs get written out to LogCat so you can see them.

Comment: That code could be anywhere doesn't look like the main thread.  If it was in the main thread it would start with an event on the main thread now wouldn't it.

Comment: Maybe you need a bitmap descriptor and not the bitmap.

Comment: @danny117: "That code could be anywhere doesn't look like the main thread" -- it is calling `setImageBitmap()` on an `ImageView`. Hence, it is being called on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are mostly incorrect.  Hence this can be done in the background thread.  Why don't you go look at the link maybe that was the issue.  I'm afraid too look at the link.

Comment: @danny117: You are certainly welcome to provide a complete sample project that demonstrates calling `setImageBitmap()` on an `ImageView` on a background thread and having it succeed.